# Cannot retrieve questions/information from phpmyAdmin database tables

Tags: javascript, php, database, mysqli

I used a youtube guide in order to create an online quiz, but I cannot get the quiz to retrieve the questions from my localhost database using MAMP.

The following are the php files I am using:

quiz.php

```
<?php
/*
Presentation & Test Quiz
*/
session_start();
if(isset($_GET['question'])){
    $question = preg_replace('/[^0-9]/', "", $_GET['question']);
    $next = $question + 1;
    $prev = $question - 1;
    if(!isset($_SESSION['qid_array']) && $question != 1){
        $msg = "Sorry! No cheating.";
        header("location: index.php?msg=$msg");
        exit();
    }
    if(isset($_SESSION['qid_array']) && in_array($question, $_SESSION['qid_array'])){
        $msg = "Sorry, Cheating is not allowed. You will now have to start over.";
        unset($_SESSION['answer_array']);
        unset($_SESSION['qid_array']);
        session_destroy();
        header("location: index.php?msg=$msg");
        exit();
    }
    if(isset($_SESSION['lastQuestion']) && $_SESSION['lastQuestion'] != $prev){
        $msg = "Sorry, Cheating is not allowed. You will now have to start over.";
        unset($_SESSION['answer_array']);
        unset($_SESSION['qid_array']);
        session_destroy();
        header("location: index.php?msg=$msg");
        exit();
    }
}
?>
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<title>Quiz Page</title>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<script type="text/javascript">
function countDown(secs,elem) {
    var element = document.getElementById(elem);
    element.innerHTML = "You have "+secs+" seconds remaining.";
    if(secs < 1) {
        var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
        var url = "userAnswers.php";
            var vars = "radio=0"+"&qid="+<?php echo $question; ?>;
            xhr.open("POST", url, true);
            xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
            xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if(xhr.readyState == 4 && xhr.status == 200) {
            alert("You did not answer the question in the allotted time. It will be marked as incorrect.");
            clearTimeout(timer);
    }
}
xhr.send(vars);
        document.getElementById('counter_status').innerHTML = "";
        document.getElementById('btnSpan').innerHTML = '<h2>Times Up!</h2>';
        document.getElementById('btnSpan').innerHTML += '<a href="quiz.php?question=<?php echo $next; ?>">Click here now</a>';

    }
    secs--;
    var timer = setTimeout('countDown('+secs+',"'+elem+'")',1000);
}
</script>
<script>
function getQuestion(){
    var hr = new XMLHttpRequest();
        hr.onreadystatechange = function(){
        if (hr.readyState==4 && hr.status==200){
            var response = hr.responseText.explode("|");
            if(response[0] == "finished"){
                document.getElementById('status').innerHTML = response[1];
            }
            var nums = hr.responseText.explode(",");
            document.getElementById('question').innerHTML = nums[0];
            document.getElementById('answers').innerHTML = nums[1];
            document.getElementById('answers').innerHTML += nums[2];
        }
    }
hr.open("GET", "questions.php?question=" + <?php echo $question; ?>, true);
  hr.send();
}
function x() {
        var rads = document.getElementsByName("rads");
        for ( var i = 0; i < rads.length; i++ ) {
        if ( rads[i].checked ){
        var val = rads[i].value;
        return val;
        }
    }
}
function post_answer(){
    var p = new XMLHttpRequest();
            var id = document.getElementById('qid').value;
            var url = "userAnswers.php";
            var vars = "qid="+id+"&radio="+x();
            p.open("POST", url, true);
            p.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
            p.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if(p.readyState == 4 && p.status == 200) {
            document.getElementById("status").innerHTML = '';
            alert("Thanks, Your answer was submitted"+ p.responseText);
            var url = 'quiz.php?question=<?php echo $next; ?>';
            window.location = url;
    }
}
p.send(vars);
document.getElementById("status").innerHTML = "processing...";  
}
</script>
<script>
window.oncontextmenu = function(){
    return false;
}
</script>
<style type="text/css">
.header {
    text align: center;
    background-image: url(Header_graphic.png);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    padding-bottom: 20px;
}
#header-logo {
    text-align: right;
    padding-top: 20px;
    padding-right: 20px;
}
h2 {
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 26px;
    font-family: WeblySleek UI Light;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    margin-top: -44px;
}
.content {
    padding-top:50px;
    padding-left: 20px;
    padding-right: 20px;
    padding-bottom:50px;
    font-family: WeblySleek UI;
    font-size: 16px;
    color: #4a4745;
}
#status {
    font-size: 14px;
    font-family: WeblySleek UI;
    color: #4a4745;
}
#counter_status {
    font-size: 14px;
    font-family: WeblySleek UI;
    color: #4a4745;
}
#question {
    font-size: 14px;
    font-family: WeblySleek UI;
    color: #4a4745;
}
#answers {
    font-size: 14px;
    font-family: WeblySleek UI;
    color: #4a4745;
}
.footer {
    width: 100%;
    margin-top: -10px;
}
</style>
</head>

<body onLoad="getQuestion()">
<div class="header">
<div id="header-logo">
    <img src="ESGPLC Logo_white_for quiz.png" />
</div>
<h2>ESGPLC HEALTH, SAFETY & ENVIRONMENT QUIZ TEST</h2>
   </div>

<div class="content">
<div id="status"></div>
<div id="counter_status"></div>
<div id="question"></div>
<div id="answers"></div>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">countDown(60,"counter_status");</script>

<div class="footer">
   <img src="http://localhost/quiz/ESGPLC_BSBS_Footer.png" />
 </div>
</body>
</html>
```

and this, question.php:

```
<?php 
/*
Presentation & Test Quiz
*/
session_start();
require_once("scripts/connect_db.php");
$arrCount = "";
if(isset($_GET['question'])){
    $question = preg_replace('/[^0-9]/', "", $_GET['question']);
    $output = "";
    $answers = "";
    $q = "";
    $sql = mysqli_query("SELECT id FROM questions");
    $numQuestions = mysqli_num_rows($sql);
    if(!isset($_SESSION['answer_array']) || $_SESSION['answer_array'] < 1){
        $currQuestion = "1";
    }else{
        $arrCount = count($_SESSION['answer_array']);
    }
    if($arrCount > $numQuestions){
        unset($_SESSION['answer_array']);
        header("location: index.php");
        exit();
    }
    if($arrCount >= $numQuestions){
        echo 'finished|<p>There are no more questions. Please enter your first and last name and click next</p>
                <form action="userAnswers.php" method="post">
                <input type="hidden" name="complete" value="true">
                <input type="text" name="username">
                <input type="submit" value="Finish">
                </form>';
        exit();
    }
    $singleSQL = mysqli_query("SELECT * FROM questions WHERE id='$question' LIMIT 1");
        while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($singleSQL)){
            $id = $row['id'];
            $thisQuestion = $row['question'];
            $type = $row['type'];
            $question_id = $row['question_id'];
            $q = '<h2>'.$thisQuestion.'</h2>';
            $sql2 = mysqli_query("SELECT * FROM answers WHERE question_id='$question' ORDER BY rand()");
            while($row2 = mysqli_fetch_array($sql2)){
                $answer = $row2['answer'];
                $correct = $row2['correct'];
                $answers .= '<label style="cursor:pointer;"><input type="radio" name="rads" value="'.$correct.'">'.$answer.'</label> 
                <input type="hidden" id="qid" value="'.$id.'" name="qid"><br /><br />
                ';
            }
            $output = ''.$q.','.$answers.',<span id="btnSpan"><button onclick="post_answer()">Submit</button></span>';
            echo $output;
           }
        }
?>
```

connect-db.php

```
<?php
$db_host = 'localhost'; 
$db_username = 'root';
$db_pass = 'root';
$db_name = 'esgplc_hse_induction';

$con = mysqli_connect($db_host, $db_username, $db_pass, $db_name);

    if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {

        echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();

}
?>
```

I cant see where I am going wrong. I understand MySQL changed to mysqli which I have updated in the code.

Many thanks,

Comment: `$sql = mysqli_query("SELECT id FROM questions");` you didn't connect, same for the other(s). RTM http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.query.php - we also don't know which API you're using to connect with.

Comment: I am not really sure what you mean. New to this. I have a connect_db.php file. My database in phpmyAdmin contains a table called questions, that has 4 fields; id, question_id, question and type. This is where the questions should be obtained from. Everything is stored in http://localhost/quiz folder. No error codes appear when the quiz is run. just the questions and multiple choice answers are missing. Using Windows PC

Comment: `$query_variable= mysqli_query($connection, "QUERY...` => `$query_variable= mysqli_query($connection, "QUERY...` where `$connection` is the variable used to connect with in your connection file and this only being an example, since I do not know what you have inside the connect_db.php file.

Comment: so, where are we with the question? Did you try my "example"? you are indeed (successfully) connecting with `mysqli_` and not `mysql_` or PDO I hope.

Comment: I have added the connect_db.php file above

Comment: and I have added my answer below, which outlines what I wrote in comments.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I mentioned in comments. The `mysqli_query()` function requires a database parameter be passed to it.

- None of your queries contain it.

Example:

```
$singleSQL = mysqli_query($con, "Your query...");
```

and apply that logic to all your queries.

Reference:

- http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.query.php

Check for errors also:

- http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.error.php
- http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php

Look into using a prepared statement also:

- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement

Comment: I understand now. I will try it and get back to you.

Comment: I have added the database parameter to the queries that needed it but still no joy

Comment: @NisaaRoberts You do have mysql/php installed, correct? How are you accessing that file, as `http://localhost/file.xxx` or as `file:///file.xxx`? Did you also add error reporting to all your php files? There is a link for it in my answer.

Comment: I have changed hr.responseText.explode to hr.responseText.split in function getQuestion. Possible multiple choice answers are now displaying but no question header as of yet and submitting an answer doesn't stop the timer.

Comment: I use http://localhost/quiz/file.php, I have no problems accessing the php files that are in the quiz folder of the root folder

Comment: @NisaaRoberts If this is a JS problem, I am not the guy for this; that isn't something I am good at. Try your query without the JS and see if that works. Look at your developer console to see if any errors come of it.